# Django2.0 Collectstatic and Admin Issue

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, collectstatic

I'm deploying my `Django web application` into my new server in order to set production application.

After 2 days in order to config `Apache2` and `wsgi`, I'm getting a new issue according to static files and Administration static page.

## My Production Environment :

- Ubuntu Server 16.4
- Django 2.0.1
- Python 3.5.2
- Apache 2.4
- WSGI

## My Static environment :

```
DatasystemsCORE
├── DatasystemsCORE
│   ├── settings.py
├── API-GED
├── Authentification
├── Configuration
├── Templates
├── static
│   ├── Theme
│      ├── Theme1
│          ├── css
│          ├── js
│          ├── images
│          ├── flags
│      ├── Theme2
│          ├── css
│          ├── js
│          ├── images
│          ├── flags
├── ...
```

As you can see, I have a static directory which contains all static files in function of choosen theme.

I have to make : `python3 manage.py collectstatic` in order to import static files according to Administration part in my static directory.

## My settings.py file :

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
THEME_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "Theme/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), THEME_DIRS, ]

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

## TraceBack :

```
Copying '/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static/Theme/Datasystems/css/Base.css'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 189, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 354, in copy_file
    self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 49, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 236, in _save
    os.makedirs(directory)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/home/valentin/.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/static'
```

I don't understand why Django is creating static directory outside of my existing static directory ? Why I have permission denied ?

How I can import Admin static element into my static directory ?

I assume static files coming from this path : `.virtualenvs/DSCoreEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/`

Comment: Your question is confusing because it's a mixture of made-up names like  `APP1` and real names like `DatasystemsCORE`. Note that [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) should normally be outside of your Django project. It shouldn't be under version control. The `collectstatic` command will collect static files from the admin app *and* the directories in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Make sure that the user running `collectstatic` has the correct permissions.

Comment: I edit my question according to DatasystemsCORE and APPn. I would like to gather all static files, directories into an unique static directory. It's done in my Django project except with admin application.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand that `STATIC_ROOT` is a separate directory where files are collected to.. It should not be contained in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (a list of directories that static files are collected from). Currently, your `STATIC_ROOT` setting is trying to collect all static files into `/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/static`, but the user running `manage.py collectstatic` does not have permissions to create that directory.

Comment: Ok I understood. I modified settings.py in order to get a new static directory in `/var/www/html` (i.e outside of my Django project). Then I executed `collectstatic` and 1294 static files copied to this new directory. Finally, my administration interface don't have css style loaded. I have to modify something else ?

Comment: Now you need to configure Apache to serve your new static directory. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) for more info.

Comment: It works @Alasdair ! I modified Apache2 too and it should work fine !
Maybe you could add an answer and I will validate it ?
Thank you !

Comment: Glad you got it working. Since you know the code that worked, it would probably be easier for you to add your own answer.

Comment: Yes, I will add my detailled answer tomorrow !
Thank you one more time @Alasdair

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer based on Alasdair's answer who helped me to solve my issue.

I didn't overcome to collect static files because my directory was inside my Django Web Project. It was a mistake and I created a new directory outside of my Django Project.

I specified the path in my settings.py file. Then, I executed this command :

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Actually, all static files are in my ne directory, outside of Django Project and it works fine !